# Android Studio - Some of the features are not working

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I have a problem with Android Studio. It does not show any error(If has) on some classes or show error even if there is not an error but application compiles succesfuly. Also refactoring not working sometimes.

Things I tried:
Removed Android Studio cache.
Invalidate caches and restart.
Installing JDK, Android Studio, SDK again.
Installing operating system again.

None of them solved my problem. Weird thing is code inspection works on some classes but not working on some classes. I have to write without auto import etc. It works like a simple notepad. On the other hand, sometimes I can not copy or remove any text on the program. Are the any solution for this problem?

You won't believe me It happened to me while even using it with MAC and different project.

[Android Studio not showing any error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQF70.png)

[Refactoring not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2XGW.png)

Android Studio logs

Full Log Here:
[Full Log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zAwCG8zXqnYspfx811ypHIwCabwnh9az/view?usp=sharing)

The piece that interests me:
[Part of log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSJbP.png)

Comment: if there is error in your code, you have check using logcat. You will bet possible direction to the error. In case of refractoring, how are you trying to acheive it ?

Comment: Right click on the file/folder -> refractor - rename.

Comment: Moving file or refactoring file name not working. As a said the weird thing is, as you can see on the image there is no icon for DetailsActivity.java file but there is "C (Class maybe)" icon for ProjectAdapter.java file. So as a summary, Android Studio can't recognize some classes even if it has no problem with syntax etc.

Comment: what version are you using ?

Comment: I'm using Android Studio 4.0 but there was a problem with 3.6 too

Comment: well I am using the same. Never had any issues with the refractoring and also class recognization

Comment: did you try, File -> invalidate cache/restart

Comment: Yes I tried as i mentioned

Comment: its quite strange.

Comment: Please share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE and reproducing the issue.

Comment: Sorry for late answer, I managed to share the log(Edited my post). Please let me know if you have any idea. Thanks in advance. There is an error for my DetailsActivity.java file as it seems

Comment: Have you tried refreshing Gradle? Maybe the errors only appear on code that uses libraries that may not be synced? Click the elephant icon with "Sync Project with Gradle Files".

Comment: I have just tried but not working..

Comment: Please try to remove all IDE related data (.iml file and .idea folder) and reimport project again.

Comment: I bought an ssd yesterday and made a fresh install but didn't solve my problem. It drives me crazy but I do not care from now(Writing code without auto complete, import). Perhaps, the problem is computer's local language(Turkish), line endings etc. As a result I'm done with it :) Thanks for trying to help me but from now I lost my faith on the solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added kotlin support for Android studio, problem solved.